# Python coding repeating the same string 10 times with counts on each of them

Tags: python

instead of:

```
print('a', 1)
print('a', 2)
```

and upto

```
print('a', 10)
```

how do you get the same results using a simpler code?
This is on my exam but i dont know how to do it and have no idea. please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop to iterate over a `range`:

```
for i in range(1, 11)::
    print('a', i)
```